# Use validation for multifields

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I tried to add a validation like validate_change, but containing two fields, :from_id, :to_id. I want to test that this tuple is in a Management table, or it shouldn't be inserted:

```
  def changeset_create(%Task{} = task, attrs) do
    task
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :body, :finished, :from_id, :to_id])
    |> validate_required([:title, :body, :finished, :from_id, :to_id])
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:from_id)
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:to_id)
    |> validate_in_management()
  end

  def validate_in_management(changeset, _opts \\ []) do
    changeset
    |> validate_change(:from_id
  end
```

But I don't know how to do it in next step, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problemn by not using `validate_change` but use a `validate_in_management(changeset, _opts \\ [])` and

```
changeset
  |> add_error(:from_id, "not find from and to in management table.")
```

to get the right changeset.